# Signing document by "Signing Group" member

Tags: docusignapi

I created Signing Group in DocuSign. Now, using SigningGroupId I'm trying to sign document by SOAP API. My template contains two signers, first one is regular participant second is signing group. I'm able to create envelope and sign document as first participant. When I try to do it for signing group I receive message:

> Additional information: The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope.

```
  public string GetTokenForEnvelopeId(string envelopeId, SigningParam signingParam, RecipientParam recipient)
    {
        RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs urls = MappClientURLs(signingParam);

        if (_client == null)
            _client = CreateClient();

        RequestRecipientTokenAuthenticationAssertion assert = CreateAssertion();

        return _client.RequestRecipientToken(envelopeId, ClientUserID, recipient.Name, recipient.Email, assert, urls);
    }
```

`recipient.Name` and `Email` are one of signing group member. `ReqestRecipientToken` is method from API. Any idea what I do wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using SOAP, but was able to do this with a REST call which should be similar in terms of what to pass through. Omit the email and name, you just need to add the signingGroupId for that recipient. Here's my snippet for an envelope creation request:

```
            "signers" : [{
            "recipientId" : "3",
            "signingGroupId":"928",
            "routingOrder" : "3",
            "tabs" : {
              "signHereTabs" : [{
                  "anchorString" : "Sign2",
                  "tabLabel" : "Sign Here 2"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: I just realised you are using a client - not sure if signing groups is supported via the client, but check if you are able to use on the signingGroupId.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When you send only group Id how docusign know what signature should be put in the document? I thought, we create envelope with product group recipient than, if one of the member what to sign it his email and name should be send. What do you think ?

Comment: Hi Tomaz, the point of the signing group is that you ( and DocuSign) doesn't know who the signer will be, but will accept a signature from any member of the signing group. That's why you do not specify the name and email.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign support said signing group is not supported in API (SOAP and REST) yet. They will keep me posted.